# submitting form a second time, renders the previous partial as well as the current

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I am submitting a single text area form via :remote => true.  It works great, however if I submit the form twice without reloading the page it renders the partial 3 times.  Once on the first submission, then if I enter new text and submit it again it loads the previous partial as well as the current one, resulting in what appears to be 3 submits.  It only submits to the database twice, on page refresh one of them dissapears.
My controller looks like so:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to(return_to) }
    format.js
  end
```

and my this is my js:

```
$('.comment_form').bind('ajax:success', function(){
    $(this).closest('.post').children('.comment_container').prepend("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'public/comment', :object => @comment) %>");
    $('.notice').html('<p>New Comment Added</p>');
    $(this).children(':input').val('');
    $(this).closest('.comment_form_div').slideUp();
    return false;
});
```

I am including jquery and jquery-ujs only once, and I have tried setting `$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});` but to no avail.

Has anyone else run into this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just a heads up in case anyone else has this problem.

I had to do:

```
$('#post_form').bind('ajax:complete', function(){
    $('#post_form').unbind('ajax:success');
});
```